# Why don't columns with citext datatype is processed by presto?

Tags: postgresql, presto, presto-jdbc

I'm running pgsql queries on the sql console provided by presto-client connected to presto-server running on top of **postgres**. The resultset of the queries contain only the columns that aren't of **citext** type.

**DataDetails Table Description:**

```
                                   Table "public.datadetails"
      Column      |   Type   |          Modifiers           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------------+----------+------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 data_sequence_id | bigint   | not null                     | plain    |              | 
 key              | citext   | not null                     | extended |              | 
 uploaded_by      | bigint   | not null                     | plain    |              | 
 uploaded_time    | bigint   | not null                     | plain    |              | 
 modified_by      | bigint   |                              | plain    |              | 
 modified_time    | bigint   |                              | plain    |              | 
 retrieved_by     | bigint   |                              | plain    |              | 
 retrieved_time   | bigint   |                              | plain    |              | 
 file_name        | citext   | not null                     | extended |              | 
 file_type        | citext   | not null                     | extended |              | 
 file_size        | bigint   | not null default 0::bigint   | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "datadetails_pk1" PRIMARY KEY, btree (data_sequence_id)
    "datadetails_uk0" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (key)
Check constraints:
    "datadetails_file_name_c" CHECK (length(file_name::text) <= 32)
    "datadetails_file_type_c" CHECK (length(file_type::text) <= 2048)
    "datadetails_key_c" CHECK (length(key::text) <= 64)
```

**Query Result in Presto-Client:**

```
presto:public> select * from datadetails;

 data_sequence_id | uploaded_by | uploaded_time | modified_by | modified_time | retrieved_by | retrieved_time | file_size |
------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+
    2000000000007 |    15062270 | 1586416286363 |           0 |             0 |            0 |              0 |        61 |
    2000000000011 |    15062270 | 1586416299159 |           0 |             0 |     15062270 |  1586417517045 |        36 |
(2 rows)

Query 20200410_130419_00017_gmjgh, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 17 total, 17 done (100.00%)
0:00 [2 rows, 0B] [10 rows/s, 0B/s]
```

In the above resultset it is evident that the columns with **citext** type are missing.

Does presto support the citext datatype or Is there any configuration to process the citext datatype using presto?

Postgres: **PostgreSQL 9.4.0-relocatable (Red Hat 4.4.7-11), 64-bit**

Presto-Server: **presto-server-0.230**

Presto-Client: **presto-cli-332**

Comment: Did you try `SET SESSION postgres.unsupported_type_handling = 'CONVERT_TO_VARCHAR';` ?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen No, I haven't tried. I'm totally out of clue about this. Where should I set this property?

Comment: On the presto CLI, before running your query. Replace "postgres" with your actual catalog name.